# Ajax con CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy intentando realizar una función que envie datos en un archivo php con `ajax` con el siguiente código:

```
function buscar(){
var texto = $("#search").val(); 
var pagina = $("#pagina").val(); 

var datos_formulario = "texto="+texto+"&pagina="+pagina;
 console.log(datos_formulario);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/prestamos-2017/backend/includes/buscar',
    data: datos_formulario,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (objeto) {

    },
    success: function (json) {
        console.log(json)
       //$('.lista').html(json.registros);
        //$(".btp").on("click", function(){
          //  $( "#tareaInput" ).focus();
        //});
        //tarea_completa(fecha_actual);
        //color();


    },
    error: function (e) {
          console.log('No se puede conectar al servidor');
    },
    complete: function (objeto, exito, error) {

    }
});
```

}

Pero da un error en consola que dice:

> POST http://localhost/prestamos-2017/backend/includes/buscar 403 (Forbidden)

En mi archivo `routes.php` del `codeigniter` tengo la siguiente linea:

```
$route['backend/includes/buscar'] = 'includes/buscar';
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

   class Buscar extends CI_Controller {

        var $data;
        var $current_user_id;

        function __construct(){
             parent::__construct();
             $this->data->item_slug = 'motherform';
             $this->data->text_item = 'formulario';
             $this->data->text_items = 'formularios';
             $this->data->text_gender = 'f';
        }

        function buscar() {
             $this->load->view('backend/includes/buscar.php');   
        }
    } ?>
```

Comment: al parecer se trata de un error de permisos

Comment: al parecer si, pero no logro dando les los permisos

Comment: ponme la funcion de la controller y de la vista el elemento que llama la funcion buscar

Comment: ya edite mi pregunta, gracias

Comment: te puede estar faltando el token de csrf fijate este hilo https://stackoverflow.com/a/10794847/1423096

Answer (score 0):

Revisa esta forma de realizar la peticion:

```
$.ajax({
                            // cargamos url a nuestro contralador y método indicado
                            url:"<?php echo site_url();?>/backend/includes/buscar",
                            type:"post",
                            success:function(data){
                                if(data){
                                    alert(data)
                                }
                                else{
                                    alert("error")
                                }
                            }
                        })
```

Y recuerda que de la controller estamos enviando para la vista datos tipo json. Prueba a quitando `$this->load->view('backend/includes/buscar.php');` de la funcion buscar de la controller y ponle esto echo `json_encode(array(‘mensaje’=> 'Hola Mundo'));` para pasar a la vista un dato y muestralo con una alerta en la vista dentro del `success` a ver si te sigue dando el error:

Comment: aun tengo le mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Revisa este link: https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-jquery-ajax-post/
En el te da un explicacion detallada del uso de ajax con codeigniter